# Catch parameter from URL, pass parameter to a function, execute that function

Tags: php, function, url

I have seen a case where for example a URL like this http://example.com/?edit=39 straight away opens a page where you can edit **only** the article/post which has ID = 39.
I have read a lot about calling a function via URL but I have never met the case where you can catch parameter from the URL, pass the parameter into the function and then execute the function.

Using URL http://example.com/?edit=39 as example, how do I use a function to identify 39 as the ID and retrieve a post from the database which has ID = 39.

Comment: $id=$_REQUEST['edit'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example your URL is `test.php?edit=39`

```
if (isset($_GET['edit'])) {// it will catch the 39
    $id= $_GET['edit'];
     $return_value=funciton_name($id);// passing parameter to the function
     echo $return_value;// it will display the return vlaue.
}
```

//execute that function and return the value

```
function funciton_name($id){
    $result1 = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id=".$id;
    return $result1;
}
```

Comment: @Narenda, thank you for this. You got me on the right path

Answer (score 1):

Use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) functions.

For example

`$parts = parse_url($url);
parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
echo $query['email'];`

If you want to get the `$url` dynamically have a look at this below question: 
[Get the full URL in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php)

Comment: Thank @seravee, however I did not understand   $query['email']. where from the ['email']?

Comment: @Elizabeth Kof email is an argument if suppose it contains in the arguments i given as a sample format. for your URL it should be edit.